# How to dynamically change ListView color (skip one line)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Using VB.Net and tried many times to achieve this but couldn't get it worked.

I just need to achieve the below on a ListView

```html
dim myRow as string

For Each myRow in ListView

  ListView1.BackColor = Color.Blue

Next
```

[ListView image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zsii.png)

[ListView1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJDcu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Mod` operator.

```
    Dim myListView As ListView
    Dim myRow As ListViewItem
    Dim rowCnt As Integer = 0
    For Each myRow In myListView.Items
        If rowCnt Mod 2 = 0 Then
            myRow.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Else
            myRow.BackColor = Color.Gray
        End If
        rowCnt = rowCnt + 1
    Next
```

Comment: Do you need to have `ListViewItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems` set to `True` for this to work?

Comment: Don't have that **UseItemStyleForSubItems** in my VS 2013 ??   it underlines it in red !!!

Comment: No, you shouldn't need anything more than what I have posted (aside from actually assigning your `ListView` instance to the `myListView` variable).

Comment: Thanks gmiley. It works !!. I was putting the function before the ListView items loads whereas it should have been after all items (lines are filled) are loaded into ListView1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BackColor` property for `ListViewItem`.

```
Dim i As Integer
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView.Items
    If i Mod 2 = 0
        lvi.BackColor = Color.Gold
    End If
    i += 1   
Next
```

*I have following example working:*

```
ListView1.Items.Add("test1")
        ListView1.Items.Add("test2")
        ListView1.Items.Add("test3")
        ListView1.Items.Add("test4")

        Dim i As Integer

        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            lvi.SubItems.Add("s1")
            lvi.SubItems.Add("s2")
        Next


        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                lvi.BackColor = Color.Gold
            End If
            i += 1
        Next
```

I have also added two 3 columns with `Columns` property in designer mode, and set `View` property equal to `Details`.

Comment: None of these codes work !! I have my ListView called in Form1 (Form1.ListView1).  @ M ldrees : is your code complete??

Comment: @ M ldrees : is your code complete?? Seems there's **If** without **End If**

Comment: `%` is not a valid character in VB.NET. Switch it with `Mod`

Comment: I did, but still not working.   I wrote this : Dim i As Integer
        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView1.Items
            If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                lvi.BackColor = Color.Gold
                i += 1

            End If

        Next

Comment: Still not working. I changed "ListView.Items" to Form1.ListView1.Items, as my ListView is located on Form1

Comment: Can you put some detail. what not working. Getting any error? or not get colored ?

Comment: Can you post the screen shot. How many items and subitems your listview has? or the code how you are populating the listview. Also do you have defined any columns?

Comment: It also depends on what you have set the `View` property of listview. I have working with `View` property set to `Details`

Comment: I added the screenshot of my ListView. BTW, my listView contains only one column at the moment, and is located on Form1.  There's no error !!! It doesn't change the color. The color is still the same like on the attached picture.  If you want, you can attach a zip file of your project so that I can see. I'm working on VB.Net not C# !!